# How to use ItemsControl with WrapPanel to list items separated by a comma?

Tags: wpf, binding, relativesource

I have an ItemsControl which lists items by separating them with a comma. The code is the following:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text=", " 
                           Name="commaTextBlock"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <!-- Hide the first comma -->
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" 
                             Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" 
                            TargetName="commaTextBlock" 
                            Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The result is something like this: Item1, Item2, Item3

Now, I'd like to do the same using a WrapPanel instead of a StackPanel as the ItemsPanelTemplate. I tested it and it works fine, except for a small detail, it does something like this:

Item1, Item2

, Item3

Of course this is because the comma is before each element and I hide the first one. I would like to put the comma after each element and hide the last one, so the result would be this:

Item1, Item2,

Item3

It would be really simple if there existed something like NextData (so I would bind to this instead of to PreviousData), but unfortunately no such thing exists (or I haven't found one). Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: +1 this is a really handy WPF example even without the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use multibinding and a converter. Something like this:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock>
      <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
          <Binding Mode="OneWay"/>
          <Binding ElementName="root" Path="ItemsSource" Mode="OneWay"/>
        </MultiBinding>
      </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
  </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Where `root` is the name of your ItemsControl.

And write a converter which checks for position:

```
public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var text = values[0] as string;
        var list = values[1] as ObservableCollection<string>;

        //check for null etc...

        if (list.IndexOf(text) == list.Count - 1)
            return text;

        return string.Format("{0}, ", text);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       //ignore this, not gonna happen with OneWay Binding 
       return null;
    }
}
```

Works for me! Hope it helps you with your problem!

**EDIT**:
Almost the same as the other answer, the difference here is that you only need 1 `TextBlock` in your template, and the converter decides if there is a comma or not. But basically the same principle. `MultiBinding` rocks! :-)

Comment: I accepted this solution since it is the one I decided to use (I prefer having just one text box), but both solutions work well and are nearly the same. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4):

I have done a visibility converter for a similar problem:

```
<TextBlock Text=", " Name="commaTextBlock"> 
   <TextBlock.Visibility>
       <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource commaVisibilityConverter}">
       <Binding ElementName="myItemsControl" Path="ItemsSource"/>
       <Binding/>
    </MultiBinding>                            
   </TextBlock.Visibility>
</TextBlock>
```

And the [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) logic:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var collection = values[0] as IEnumerable<MyItem>;
        var item = values[1] as MyItem;
        if ((collection != null) && (item != null) && (collection.Count() > 0))
        {
            return collection.Last() == item ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
        }          

        return Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry I accepted the other solution, but thanks for the help anyway!